# There is something wrong with my Puny code

Tags: javascript, punycode

I wanted to create a function that using pure JavaScript and without any dependencies. However, my function doesn't seem to provide the correct result. I intended for the domain to still be accessible and functional in web browsers.

This is what I have so far

```js
function convrtToP(url) {
    const urlObj = new URL(url);
    const hostname = urlObj.hostname;
  
    const punycodeHostname = Array.from(hostname)
      .map(char => char.match(/[A-Za-z0-9\-._~]/) ? char : `xn--${char.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)}`)
      .join('');
  
    urlObj.hostname = punycodeHostname;
  
    return urlObj.href;
  }
  
  // Test cases
  const url1 = "https://www.anti-ärger.com";
  
  console.log(convrtToP(url1)); // Output: https://www.xn--anti-rger-z2a.com
```

Comment: What are your expected outputs for the test cases?

Comment: what are the desired outcomes for each of the test cases? Further, why do you want to convert the symbols into latin-based strings?

Comment: @MahanLamee the  Output: https://www.xn--anti-rger-z2a.com should be the expected sorry for that..

Comment: @Rakushoe But your code is giving the exact expected results. Also I don't get what you're trying to do. Are you trying to remove the special characters entirely? Is xn-- just a prefix that should be added to all URLs?

Comment: @MahanLamee but doesn't appear to give me the correct result maybe at your end. Thank you for this.. I will take a deeper look at this why.

Comment: I think they @MahanLamee means that the expected outcome you've outline in the question is what is being returned by the StackOverflow snippet? (At least on Chrome)

Comment: @Harrison aw I see I will try to rephrase.. thanks

Comment: I am getting the expected result for all three cases with your snippet above, are you getting something different _there_ as well? If not - what character encoding did you actually save your file that you are trying this in on your system, in ...?

Comment: @Rakushoe Your current code seems to be working fine. I can copy the resulting URLs and they point me to the same websites as the test cases. The issue might be related to your file's encoding.

Comment: Thank you for this info I will consider checking the character encode that I use in saving it..

Comment: The only difference is that your code appends a trailing slash. I presume that's an artefact of using of `URL` class, which seemingly produces a normalised URL for empty path components.

Answer (score 3):

Browsers contain a converter; calling `new URL` is all you need to do. From the console:

```
new URL("https://grå.org").hostname
'xn--gr-zia.org'
```

The map/join call in the question is a no-op because by the time it's called the result is already in the desired format.

The map call is also *wildly* different from the punycode algorithm; don't even think of implementing punycode with a map like that.

Comment: I tried this arnt but it does not handle Punycode conversion for Internationalized Domain Names

Comment: I didn't type that code and the output, I copied it from Chrome's console, which proves that it works on Chrome… I see you made mistakes with your encoding. Make sure your test cases actually are valid. All of the three major browsers will reject some IDNs, [here is Chrome's policy](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/idn.md#google-chrome_s-idn-policy) for example. If you fumble the encodings on your test cases you can easily insert something the browsers will reject.